# Running bits of code in a separate kernel

Tags: export, parallelization, kernel, crash, kernel-startup

I am using Mathematica to generate 3D graphics frame for a video. The process goes as follows:

- Loop over a counter `i`

  - Use `Import` to load in data from `data.$i.hdf5` into `data`
  - Apply some expression to `data`, then use `Interpolation` on it
  - Make a `ParametricPlot3D` of the surface with `PlotPoints -> 50` and store it in `outgfx`
  - Export result to `outgfx.png` with `ImageSize -> {2048, 2048}`

The problem is that MathKernel keeps **crashing** every 3-5 frames with no reason given. I tried putting the entire body of the loop in a `Block` and store all variables locally, hoping that the garbage collector would be better behaved, but this did not help. My current solution is to manually babysit Mathematica and manually change the loop limits and re-run the code every time I hear a beep.

I figured that way to sidestep this issue is to launch a new kernel for each iteration, do the processing, then shut down the kernel before looping. If the new kernel crashes, since the loop itself runs in a different kernel, it can keep going.

Is there a way to do this in the frontend?

Comment: a quick fix which will not solve your problem but probably makes it less problematic could be to set `$HistoryLength=0` which will probably help in decreasing the memory consumption. For running in extra kernels you could have a look at the parallel functionality. If you use that with only one parallel kernel and do `CloseKernels` once in a while that probably is the most convenient interface to do what you want. For your application using more than one kernel in parallel would probably also make sense. It would certainly also be possible to start a kernel with lower level functionality...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of consideration I recommend that you use [`ParallelSubmit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html) and related functionality, e.g. [`WaitAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaitAll.html).  Please consider this example:

```
job = Array[ParallelSubmit[Pause[1]; If[Random[] > 0.7, Quit[]]; Print[#]] &, 10]
```

[image]

This creates a series [`EvaluationObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationObject.html) tasks to perform.  Within each is a 30% chance of failure simulated by `If[Random[] > 0.7, Quit[]]`.  To start the job use:

```
WaitAll[job]
```

You can watch the progress of the tasks in real time by looking at the displayed output of `job`:

[image]

You will note that when a kernel "crashes" a number of messages are printed (these could be suppressed with [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html)) and the task is *tried again* on a different kernel.  Ultimately every `Print` task is performed once:

> (kernel 4) 1
>
> (kernel 3) 2
>
> (kernel 4) 5
>
> (kernel 6) 3
>
> (kernel 6) 10
>
> (kernel 8) 4
>
> (kernel 9) 6
>
> (kernel 10) 7
>
> (kernel 8) 9
>
> (kernel 11) 8

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately running 3D routines in parallel seems to cause a kernel panic on OSX... I guess I could limit the number of kernels.

Comment: @Saran Please try evaluating `CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[1]` before running this code.  That should limit it to the use of one kernel at a time.

Comment: I haven't had success with this approach, yet, as mma keeps failing on me with irreproducible symptoms (mangled graphics, black graphics, OSX kernel panic, making my entire system unresponsive). However, I will accept this answer as I think it's the closest thing there is to a solution to this problem!

Comment: @Saran I am sorry to hear of your ongoing problems.  As a Windows user I am not sure how many of them I could help with but I wish you luck.  If you post questions with as much clarity as possible and sufficient detail people here are usually willing (and able) to help.  Thanks for the Accept anyway.

Answer (score 2):

After multiple failures to achieve truly *unattended* batch plotting setup solely in Mathematica, I have finally decided to go with a hybrid approach instead. I have exported the plotting commands into a Mathematica script, then use a separate Python script to call `WolframScript`.

After a couple of plots, the `MathKernel` will *still crash* as usual. This will pass control back to the Python script, which can check the output directory to determine how far the Kernel has gotten to. It would then restart `WolframScript` again with a new starting number as appropriate.

My Python script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import os
import subprocess

r = re.compile(r"frame([0-9]{3}).png")

firstframe = 0
lastframe  = 500

def maxframe():
    out = -1
    for file in os.listdir('/path/to/input/files/'):
        m = r.match(file)
        if m:
            frame = int(m.group(1))
            if out < frame:
                out = frame
    return out

while maxframe() < lastframe:
    subprocess.call(
        './make_frame.m %u %u' % (maxframe() + 1, lastframe),
        shell = True,
        preexec_fn = os.setpgrp)
```

and the Mathematica script `make_frame.m`:

```
#!/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframScript -script

firstframe = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[2]]];
lastframe  = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[3]]];

coords = Flatten[Outer[List,
    Table[i Pi/254, {i, 0, 254}], Table[2 i Pi/128, {i, 0, 128}]], 1];

x[r_, th_, ph_] := r Sin[th] Cos[ph];
y[r_, th_, ph_] := r Sin[th] Sin[ph];
z[r_, th_, ph_] := r Cos[th];

For[n = firstframe, n <= lastframe, n++,
    data = Import[
        "/path/to/input/files/data" <> IntegerString[n, 10, 3] <> ".hdf5",
        {"Datasets", "/r"}
    ];

    rfun = Interpolation[
        Transpose[{coords, data}],
        PeriodicInterpolation -> {False, True}
    ];

    gfx = ParametricPlot3D[
        {
            x[th, ph, rfun[th, ph]],
            y[th, ph, rfun[th, ph]],
            z[th, ph, rfun[th, ph]]
        },
        {th, 0, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi},
        PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
        PlotPoints -> 50,
        Boxed -> False,
        Axes -> None
    ];

    Export[
        "/path/to/output/files/frame" <> IntegerString[n, 10, 3] <> ".png",
        gfx,
        ImageSize -> {1024, 1024}
    ];

    Print[n];
];
```